# How I can compare text and boolean condition with logical operators

Tags: php, session, comparison, operators, conditional-statements

I have an Header file which contains the menu (header.php). He is called on almost every page of the site.

I want to check if the user is logged in to show the entire page, so in the end of the file (header.php) I have add this condition :

```
if ((!isset($_SESSION["email"]) && !isset($_SESSION["password"])) or $title != "Connexion" or $title != "403") 
    { 
       header("Location: 403.php"); 
    }
```

(if user don't have session or the page title is different to page connexion ou page error, the user are redirect, else continue

I only want to allow the user to see the login page ($title = "Connexion") OR error page ($title = "403"), there is only one title in page)

In fact, if the user don't have session,  I want it to connect : login.php

```
<?php
  $title = 'Connexion'; 
  include ("/layout/header.php");
  ?>

  .....
```

But my condition don't work, Can you correct my condition?

Thank you

Comment: You should not store the password in the session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the last part of your condition:

```
... or $title != "Connexion" or $title != "403"
```

This is always true, for any `$title`, so the complete condition will always match and you enter a never-ending redirect loop.

You need something like:

```
if ( !isset($_SESSION["email"]) && $title !== "Connexion" && $title !== "403" )
```

Note that you should not store the password in the session.

Comment: It's don't work because I only want to allow the user to see the login page ($title = "Connexion") OR error page ($title = "403"), there is only one title in page, in you'r condition the title must be connexion AND 403,
Thank you

Comment: @Rocstar My mistake, they all have to be `&&` of course: When there is no session AND you are not on the login page AND you are not on the 403 page, then redirect.

Comment: Yes ! I did not take the problem as it should be ! Thank you, it's work great